# How to use Arduino to control the switch on a 4.5v circuit

Tags: arduino, voltage, current, switches

I've been building a wall mounted lightsaber using the below board.

At the moment the switch is turning it on and off, however I want to automate this with an Arduino.

Can I use a digital output pin to act as the switch and connect the Arduino ground to the ground on my board?

My power source is a 2amp 4.5v  DC.
The Arduino would plug into the USB on the same AC/DC adapter as this board.

Thanks!

[image: Wiring]

Comment: Use a logic level FET with heatsink or rated for >15A

Comment: what does the existing switch look like. how much voltage do you measure across it, how much current through it when activated?

Comment: Use an optocoupler , it will be nice , easy and safe.

Answer (score 1):

`Spectra V2` seems to be a microcontroller based LED light-show controller with a soft power button.

As such the button input only uses a very small current, if you connect a 5V arduino you should be able to use a digital IO directly,

set the arduino port output low and set the direction to input, when you want to trigger the button input change the direction to output

|You can probably use the the same 4.5V supply to run both the arduino and the Spectra. 4.5 is an acceptable VCC voltage for arduino.

Comment: This is what I am trying, however there is a large current running through the Spectra, around 2-3amps. Will the Arduino be okay with this?

Comment: @LVLYXL the power button is a gpio with an interrupt to sense when it goes low so no real current runs through it. And powering both boards off the same supply doesn't put the 2 Amps through it. The boards will pull what they need.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a relay that can handle at least 5v, and 2 amps, you can even get some. 240v relays for pretty cheap. I recommend getting a relay that has got its pins like this[image: you see that this relay is put on a board to make the pinout connections easier.]

instead of like this,
[image: this can be a bit harder to connect]
which can be a tad harder to connect, but if you know how to wire a relay, or just watch a tutorial you can buy either.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3RdTN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just use a 3.3v or a 5v microrelay and replace  the switch with it. These types of relays can directly be controlled (and powered) with arduino itself as they don't draw much current.

The relay would ensure that the connection is **external** and it can easily handle upto *10-12A of current with 20-30V.*

If required connect the relay through an **amplifying** circuit such as *transistor or op-amp*.

Comment: Typically even micro relays use more current than an arduino gpio is suitable for.

Answer (score 0):

Four normal ways of doing this, in order from most to least isolation.

1. is a relay. Any normal 5V relay (spst spdt dpdt doesn't matter) would work here. Wire the switch pins in parallel with the momentary switch. A relay module would have all you need. A smaller micro relay or reed relay would be more compact, you just need a small relay driver circuit made from a npn transistor. The relay provides full mechanical galvanic isolation. You don't need to connect anything else to the board.
2. An optocoupler. This provides optical galvanic isolation, and can be driven directly from the arduino. It's basically an led on the arduino side so simple to drive and a transistor on the output side. The relay modules tend to use one of these optocouplers too, but since the current needed is so low, you can skip the relay and drive this directly.
3. An npn transistor. No isolation, you will have to tie the arduino ground and the board grounds together for this to work. Might as well since you can power the arduino from the 4.5V supply you already have.
4. Direct drive. Connect the yellow side of the switch to a gpio through a 4.7k resistor just in case. Leave high-z/input for unpressed and pull to output low for pressed. You still have to connect the grounds together and again should just power the two boards from the same power supply.
5. Bonus. Use a solenoid to press the button. Like most of star wars, this is overkill and you could pretend it was done by the force.